# Attach player to moving platform 3d unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a player move with the moving rock, the player jumps on it and the rock takes her from a to b but right now the player is just sliding off the rock.  this is my code for the rock:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class playerattach : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Player;

    public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "movingrock")
        {
            Player.transform.parent = other.gameObject.transform;
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        Player.transform.parent = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does you player game object use the physics engine (Rigidbody)?

Comment: yeah the player does have a Rigidbody

Comment: If the platform is also a rigidbody you will probably want to use a joint. Otherwise you can try enable the `Is Kinematic` property of the player. From the docs:: **Is Kinematic** If enabled, the object will not be driven by the physics engine, and can only be manipulated by its Transform. This is useful for moving platforms or if you want to animate a Rigidbody that has a HingeJoint attached. (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Rigidbody.html?_ga=2.267334990.1132418516.1579175116-1546226697.1578069046)

Comment: Have you tried adding to the player's velocity the rock movement?

Answer (score 0):

Double check your colliders. OnTriggerEnter will only work if your player character has a collider on it that is set to a trigger. Otherwise you want to use OnCollisionEnter. You can have more than one collider on an object

Personally, I would give the rock a trigger collider, instead of the player, as well as a normal collider, that just about covers the standing area on the rock. You can then detect the player and change the parent of the player through that. That way you won't have the player getting parented to it if they touch the side of the rock or a different part of it